# 'undefined reference to' in main.o

Tags: gcc, makefile, nasm

I'm a new user here so I'll be grateful for your patience and all advices. When I call make,  I get an error:

```
gcc main.o func.o -m32 -o prog
main.o:main.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to '_fractal"
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OBJ = main.o func.o
BIN = prog
CFLAGS = -m32
$BIN: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -o main.o

func.o: func.s 
    nasm -f elf func.s
```

I have main.c and func.s files.
Anybody could explain me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: examine `func.o` to see if `_fractal` symbol is defined... Use `nm` (for example)

Comment: ok, it seems that it doesn't, i got: 00000003 t end, 00000000 T fractal, i have a function 'fractal' defined in func.s

Comment: `$BIN: $(OBJ)` is a typo. You mean `$(BIN): $(OBJ)` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses underscore prefix for function calls.

Haven't you used `fractal` instead of `_fractal` in your external assembly module?